# Eclipse Java EE Maven Project Dependency issues

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

[image]

I am trying to build a Java EE program that uses Maven.

I see that a dependency is included into the file project:

```
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j;
```

I see an error on the line log cannot be resolved on the line:

```
log.info("Created " + this);
```

The Dependency is listed under lombok/1.16.6/lombok-1.16.6.jar

How do I fix this?

If it helps the source file is here and the issue is on line 26: https://github.com/mslosarz/nextrtc-signaling-server/blob/master/src/main/Java/org/nextrtc/signalingserver/api/NextRTCEndpoint.Java

Comment: Is `log` defined like that in the dependency? (I'm skeptical it is, but I'm simply asking) If not, you need to define it. When you hover over the red x on line 26 what does it tell you?

Comment: Have you invoked `Run As -> Maven Build -> clean install`? If no, you need to actually build your project with the Maven tool or convert it to a Maven project. If you have done these things then you need to refresh the project for your now downloaded jars to be in the classpath for Eclipse to "know about" them.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line - log cannot be  resolved, I am not sure how its defined in the dependency.

Comment: Going by https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/log4j/Log4j.html it should expand out and work this way.

Comment: Maven clean and Maven Install, I don't see clean install.

Comment: did you try to clean the project in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I have both run Maven clean and run Maven Install, with it not fixing the issue.